# Dismiss Progress Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-support-library, android-progressbar

I'm trying to implement a notification with indeterminate progress bar inside it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        intent, 0);

final NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Uploading")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    builder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
            builder.setContentText("Download complete")
            .setProgress(0, 0, false);
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }
).start();
```

Now I got two problems:

1. **SOLVED** After the upload is finished I'm not able to dismiss the notification, so I've no "cancel button" or swipe gesture available. The only way to make it disappear is to click on it and launch the activity, but it's not my requirement. Should I use pending delete intent or what? **SOLVED**
2. I'm targetting API level 8+ and on older devices no progress bar is shown (pheraps for this I need another question). Should I provide a custom layout and two behaviors depending on API level?

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: k, problem 1. solved adding .setOngoing(false), after the work is finished.

Comment: Regarding question 2:

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914126/android-notifications-compatibility-with-apis